# How can I make these semi-gloss paint patches blend with the wall?

Tags: painting, paint, repainting, patching-drywall, hole-repair

I recently tried to fix a number of small holes in a wall that is painted with brown semi-gloss paint.  Unfortunately, the paint patches are still very obvious, even after several days of drying:

[image: Painted wall without obvious patches]

Notice that the color itself matches quite well - what doesn't match is the glossy-ness of the patches, particularly around the edges.  The center of each painted patch actually matches the wall quite well.

I painted these patches using the wall's original paint (although the paint is several years old, I think) using a small brush.

How can I paint over these patches so that the end result blends in with the existing wall?  Or is there some other way to blend these patches in with the wall?

Comment: This is a common issue because the sheen of the paint depends a lot on what is underneath it.  Paint over already glossy paint will be more glossy than paint over patch or drywall or primer, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have the original paint and it appears to be good, I would get a roller and work the entire area with a 2nd coat, I would work from the patches out so the roller is not putting as much paint out towards the edges this will help to fade the change in new to old and the second coat should cover the patches to not be noticable, with this said you may always be able to see the patch because you know where the repair was. But some one else may not be able to see the spots.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that multiple coats to build up the gloss on the patched areas, followed by (after curing for a few days) light rubbing with a microfiber towel or a Mr Clean eraser can knock the gloss down.  I have also pondered using burlap but that be too coarse.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to prime over the whole area, maybe even twice.  Let completely dry then roll over the area with the matching paint feathering out so it's not obvious.